# RequestMapping annotation leads to empty RequestMethod array when looking up annotation for the controller method

Tags: java, spring, reflection, spring-mvc, annotations

We're building some kind of automatic self describing REST service (live doc generation). For this we have a controller method that looks for all controller beans and fetches also the requestmapping information to display them in a nice friendly html page.

For this we use the MetadataReader (created via CachingMetadataReaderFactory) to fetch the Metadata of the class.
When we get the MethodMetaData for the public methods we find the RequestMapping annotation along with produces and value parameters, but the method field is always an empty array, although we have it configured in the source code and the mapping works. So the information should be somewhere. This is quite puzzling! :-)

EDIT: method field is empty=> The RequestMapping Annotation has a method field, which is an array of RequestMethod objects. If you try to read that from the MethodMetaData instance it's an empty array. Example: metadata.getAnnotationAttributes(RequestMapping.class.getName()).get("method")

I tried to find the reason in the spring framework source code, but haven't found the reason so far...

Any ideas?

FYI: We're using Spring 3.1

Comment: but the method field is always empty ?? describe

Comment: Please see the edit part

Comment: I don't know working(coding) of your MetadataReader, check whether there is any other way to retrieve object information because type of method attribute in @RequestMapping annotation is array of RequestMethod. i.e. RequestMethod[]

Comment: I have clarified that. Of course it's an empty array not an empty variable. My bad. The MetadataReader is a spring class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a little sample project out of my own curiosity and fiddled a little with the MetadataReader provided by Spring. For the demo I created a very simple controller which looked like this:

```
@Controller
public class SomeAnnotatedController {

   @RequestMapping(method = {RequestMethod.GET}, value = "/someUrl")
   public void someMethod() {
       // do something later
   }

}
```

I was not able to extract the correct information from the annotation using the Spring MetadataReader.

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnMethodArrayWithSpringMetadataReader() throws Exception {
    MetadataReader metadataReader = new CachingMetadataReaderFactory().getMetadataReader(SomeAnnotatedController.class.getName());
    Set<MethodMetadata> annotatedMethods = metadataReader.getAnnotationMetadata().getAnnotatedMethods(RequestMapping.class.getName());
    assertEquals(1, annotatedMethods.size());
    MethodMetadata methodMetadata = annotatedMethods.iterator().next();
    assertEquals("someMethod", methodMetadata.getMethodName());
    Map<String, Object> annotationAttributes = methodMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(RequestMapping.class.getName());
    assertTrue(annotationAttributes.containsKey("method"));
    RequestMethod[] methodAttribute = (RequestMethod[]) annotationAttributes.get("method");
    assertEquals(1, methodAttribute.length);
}
```

Running this test fails in the last line and tells you that this is an empty array...

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

Doing the same with native Java feels a little bit easier and returns the correct information.

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnMethodArrayWithPlainJava() throws Exception {
    Method method = SomeAnnotatedController.class.getDeclaredMethod("someMethod");
    RequestMapping annotation = method.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
    assertEquals(1, annotation.method().length);
    assertEquals(RequestMethod.GET, annotation.method()[0]);
}
```

So I am sorry to tell you that I did not find a solution to the problem but maybe the sample project or the documented alternative based on plain java might help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to what you have asked for, but is a very good way to do self-document the REST API's. Use the endpoint documentation controller described by Rossen Stoyanchev here in his github location: https://github.com/rstoyanchev/spring-mvc-31-demo.git

to summarize, your controller would look something like this:

```
@Controller
public class EndpointDocController {

    private final RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping;

    @Autowired
    public EndpointDocController(RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping) {
        this.handlerMapping = handlerMapping;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/endpointdoc", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void show(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("handlerMethods", this.handlerMapping.getHandlerMethods());
    }

}
```

and your jsp would refer to the attributes for method, produces, consumes, method signature this way, asssuming the hm is a handler method:

```
Patterns:${hm.key.patternsCondition.patterns}
Method: ${hm.key.methodsCondition.methods}
Method signature: ${hm.value}
Consumes: ${hm.key.consumesCondition.expressions}
Produces: ${hm.key.producesCondition.expressions}
```

Comment: Looks almost like what I need - do you mind if I ask where do you instantiate the RequestMappingHandlerMapping? All the examples I see just instantiate it with the default constructor, but it then return and empty map of handler methods :(